# Partitioning with primary key gives Error ERROR 1503 (HY000)

Tags: mysql, partitioning

It may sound similar but,I am working on partitioning on some table...the table looks like

mysql> DESC SHOPS;
+-------------------+-------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| Field             | Type        | Null | Key | Default           | Extra                       |
+-------------------+-------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| SHOP_ID           | int(255)    | NO   | PRI | NULL              |                             |
| SHOP_NAME         | varchar(50) | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| SHOP_CREATED_DATE | timestamp   | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP | on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |
+-------------------+-------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

so i have search feature where people can search only by shop name so table have around 1 million records so i wanted to RANGE partitioning on shop name alphabetically but i cant do since i have primary key shop_id and shop name can be same...and getting error

> ERROR 1503 (HY000): A PRIMARY KEY must include all columns in the
>   table's partitioning function

Solution:

```
ALTER TABLE SHOPS ADD CONSTRAINT T  UNIQUE (SHOP_ID,SHOP_NAME);
```

And do partitioning ...i cant do this because it does not make sure shop_id is unique(Primary Key)

Comment: Read this part of the documentation:  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/partitioning-limitations-partitioning-keys-unique-keys.html.  In particular, "every unique key [and primary key] on the table must use every column in the table's partitioning expression"

Comment: So i cant do partition on shops table...???is there any alternative to make sure shop id unique

Answer (score 0):

You can, and you must.  Assuming you always let `AUTO_INCREMENT` do its thing, `shop_id` will always be unique, and any index starting with `shop_id` is all you need.

`int(255)` -- The `(255)` means nothing.  An `INT` (`SIGNED`, by default) has a range of -2 billion to +2 billion and occupies 4 bytes, regardless of the `(...)` after it..

There is probably *no* performance advantage (or any other advantage) of Partitioning this table.  If you think otherwise, please show us a query that you think will benefit.

Please use `SHOW CREATE TABLE`; it is more descriptive than `DESCRIBE`.